# C#, DataGridView - New row contains trash after being selected

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

I have a datagrid that contains some columns:
**CategoryID, SubcategoryID, SubcategoryName *(Invisible, Invisible, Visible)***

When creating new subcategory, CategoryID is reqired.

I am inputing a new subcategory name from UI. If I press ENTER it ends current row edit, and selects the row below, without starting edit mode (it just gets highlighted). This temporary selection causes my SubcategoryName to go form default empty cell value *null* to *string.empty* value.

Then, when I try to send my data back to database it causes a problem. Data Adapter raises an error, saying that CategoryID cannot be null. From what I have tested this is caused by the new row containing some invisible trash. If I edit the new row and input a normal subcategory name it all goes fine (CategoryID gets inserted by a function that detects that SubcategoryName is not empty).

How do I make sure that my new row data gets deleted?

I've tryed sending ESC key with **SendKeys.Send("{ESC}")** and **DG_SubcategoryEdit.CancelEdit()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying to solve the problem I've found out, that whenever you want to insert something into a row as an addition to what the user has put there, you should always use **DefaultValuesNeeded** event instead of **RowValidated**. DefaultValuesNeeded handles deleting remainings of the row properly, if edition is not committed. If you insert anything, even a null, in **RowValidated** the row counts as edited and will try to sync itself to the database.

The confusing part (and probably a bug) is that an "edited" row containing a null is displayed as a new empty row on DataGridView bottom, not as a regular empty row. Thus, this row will raise an error saying that you cannot delete new row, should you try to delete it.